# IIS error in xp

Tags: asp.net, iis

I got a following error when i try to open my app through IIS Version: 5.1.[image: Error]

I unable to solve problem.What is `MMC` how to restart it.Thanks.
Note: OS is XP and i give full permission for `aspnetuser`.

Comment: try google, there are alot of articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MMC` stands for `Microsoft Management Console`. Describing it simply, It is a common Graphical User Interface to have different set of configurations. For example you Right Click on My Computer Icon, and click on Manage, you can see different configurations there. It is Management Instance of MMC.
This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742442.aspx) will help you a Lot

And it would be better to start Windows, However, just closing the configuration console (IIS) and re-opening it will mean Restarting the MMC console for IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915797